# Android provide call

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application wherein when the user click on the phone call button then, the application provide itself to make call through skype or viber?
I made the intent filter but how can I  call through it? Is there any way to register my application in phone system that it provides call service ?

```
 Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:000"));
 startActivity(in);
```

thank you for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`intent-filter`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) in `AndroidManifest.xml` of your Application

You will put another `<intent-filter>` tag in  your `Activity` (the `Activity` which will handle call functionality) Tag

```
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: thx for the answer can you provide me with the actions for messaging and synchronize

Comment: Hello Adil wish that can give me the action that can make my application offer messaging too and thx on advence